# UBUNTU12.04 kinect_laser.launch can't open laser

Tags: laser, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have install openni_launch,openni_camera,openni_tracker on fuerte,
roslaunch openni.launch success,i can rosrun image_view disparity_view image:=/camera/depth/disparity   to see depth image;
and also rosrun openni_tracker success;
but when i roslaunch kinect_laser.launch following,can't open laser

i don't know why?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/68290/ubuntu12.04--kinect_laser.launch-can%27t-open-laser/) by [jiemao0125](https://answers.ros.org/users/5512/jiemao0125/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2013-07-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i have run this success on ubuntu10.04,i don't if 10.04 and 12.04 have some different in kinect with fuerte

---

Originally posted by [jiemao0125](https://answers.ros.org/users/5512/jiemao0125/) with karma: 31 on 2013-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jiemao0125](https://answers.ros.org/users/5512/jiemao0125/) on 2013-07-23**:
now ,i have run it ok;
just install pointcloud_to_laser.
[www.ros.org/wiki/pointcloud_to_laserscan](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pointcloud_to_laserscan)